# The distance function of the geodesically convex manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

$M$ is a geodesically convex Riemannian manifold, that is, for any two points $p,q$ on $M$, there is a unique minimizing geodesic connecting them. Can we conclude that for any $p \in M$, the function $f(x)=(d(x,p))^2$ is smooth where $d$ is the distance function
?

Comment: $d^2(x,p)$ is presumably defined as $(d(x,p))^2$, correct?

Comment: @Squirtle: Right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  As [noted on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_%28Riemannian_manifold%29#Applications)

> "The distance function from $p$ is a smooth function except at the point $p$ itself and the cut locus."

The cut locus is the set of all points $q \in M$ such that there is more than one distinct minimizing geodesic between $q$ and $p$.  Therefore, $d$ will be smooth at all points other than $p$, and hence $d^2$ will be smooth on all of $M$.

Comment: That same Wiki page gives a different definition of the cut locus, and notes two scenarios for it to occur: (1) non-unique geodesics; (2) conjugate points.